# How to get first line from String in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a string variable in Ruby as follows:

```
puts $varString.class
puts "##########"
puts $varString
```

the output of the code above is:

```
String 
##########
my::FIrst::Line
 this id second line 
 sjdf kjsdfh jsdf 
 djsf sdk fxdj
```

I need to get only the first line from the string variable (e.g. `my::FIrst::Line`).
How can I get it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
# Ruby >= 1.8.7
$varString.lines.first
# => "my::FIrst::Line"

# Ruby < 1.8.7
$varString.split("\n").first
# => "my::FIrst::Line"
```

As a side note, avoid to use global (the `$` sign) variables.

Comment: This was useful for a project in 1.8.6 (which doesn't support #lines)

Comment: This is very inefficient in memory and performance if there are many lines, as it needs to allocate each line

Answer (score 28):

```
$varString.lines.first
```

Or, if you want to get rid of final newline in resulting string:

```
$varString.lines.first.chomp
```

Answer (score 6):

`first_line = str[/.*/]`

This solution seems to be the most efficient solution in terms of memory allocation and performance.

This uses the `str[regexp]` form, see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

**Benchmark code:**

```
require 'stringio'
require 'benchmark/ips'
require 'benchmark/memory'

str = "test\n" * 100

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('regex') { str[/.*/] }
  x.report('index') { str[0..(str.index("\n") || -1)] }
  x.report('stringio') { StringIO.open(str, &:readline) }
  x.report('each_line') { str.each_line.first.chomp }
  x.report('lines') { str.lines.first }
  x.report('split') { str.split("\n").first }
  x.compare!
end

Benchmark.memory do |x|
  x.report('regex') { str[/.*/] }
  x.report('index') { str[0..(str.index("\n") || -1)] }
  x.report('stringio') { StringIO.open(str, &:readline) }
  x.report('each_line') { str.each_line.first.chomp }
  x.report('lines') { str.lines.first }
  x.report('split') { str.split("\n").first }
  x.compare!
end
```

**Benchmark results:**

```
Comparison:
               regex:  5099725.8 i/s
               index:  4968096.7 i/s - 1.03x  slower
            stringio:  3001260.8 i/s - 1.70x  slower
           each_line:  2330869.5 i/s - 2.19x  slower
               lines:   187918.5 i/s - 27.14x  slower
               split:   182865.6 i/s - 27.89x  slower

Comparison:
               regex:         40 allocated
               index:        120 allocated - 3.00x more
            stringio:        120 allocated - 3.00x more
           each_line:        208 allocated - 5.20x more
               lines:       5064 allocated - 126.60x more
               split:       5104 allocated - 127.60x more
```

Answer (score 4):

```
str = <<DOC1
asrg
aeg
aegfr
DOC1

puts str[0..(str.index("\n")|| -1)]
```

Avoids reading the whole string in an array. (The ||-1 avoids an error if there is no line ending in the string).**EDIT** str.lines does not create an array.

Comment: +1 because this should be faster, though it is a bit more... dare I say it... Perl-ish, because it increases the line noise. :-) If dealing with a lot of text, or long lines it could be a LOT faster than splitting or using `lines`. I'd recommend adding some benchmarks to your answer to show the benefit.

Comment: @the Tin Man  Benchmaked it against `lines` and coud find no difference, no matter what the size of the string was. It turns out `lines` does not return an array but an enumerator (much better!). So now I think @Victor Deryagin's answer is best.

Comment: It won't be faster than `lines`, because, as you found, `lines` is an enumerator. It will be a lot faster than any solution, such as `split`, which creates an array, especially when the resulting array is big.

Answer (score 1):

```
puts $varString.split('\n')[0]
```

Splits the string on '\n' tokens, and get the first one

Answer (score 1):

An alternate to @steenslag's answer would be to use StringIO to get only the first line.

```
str = <<DOC1
asrg
aeg
aegfr
DOC1

puts StringIO.open(str, &:readline)
```

If the String is huge, this avoids splitting the string into a large array and reads only the first line. Note, it throws an EOFError if the string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use truncate method as well.

```rb
'Once upon a time in a world far far away'.truncate(27, separator: ' ')
# => "Once upon a time in a..."
```

```rb
.truncate(200number of characters, separator: ' ')
```

to do not cut the word in the middle, it will finish when find a space after the number of characters you choose.

[API doc](https://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate)

Comment: Please use formatting in a way that it helps get through reply. Your formatting really doesn't do that.

Comment: This doesn't return the first line, it truncates a string.
Also truncate is part of the active_support gem, it's not built into Ruby.